# Git Flow: best approach for a hotfix for an older version being merged after a new release

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging, git-flow

When Vincent Driessen [explains Git Flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#hotfix-branches) he says a hotfix branch must be merged back into the master and develop branches, with the exception that if a release branch exists, the hotfix gets merged back into the release branch instead of the develop branch. This scenario considers the release is finishing **after** the hotfix.

My question is: let's consider that a hotfix (v1.0.1) ends up taking too much time to be finished. So that the next release (v1.1.0) is finished first and gets merged back into master and develop. What about the hotfix branch? I was thinking about updating the hotfix branch with the changes introduced in master (since they aren't breaking changes) and then finishing the hotfix. Is it a good approach?

Comment: Regarding "updating the hotfix branch with the changes introduced in master": This means that v1.0.1 contains the features from v1.1.0 plus the fix. That feels plain wrong.

Comment: @A.H. I agree it seems wrong, but what would be another option? Maybe throwing away the hotfix branch and recreating it based on the latest version?

Comment: Either put the hotfix patch into the v1.1.0 release or - if that is to late - create a new hotfix for v1.1.1. In both cases the old hotfix branch for v1.0.1 dies.